# Layout Error While Using ListView Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hello I am trying to show some data to user with ListView but I get exactly this error:

```
*RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
```

My Code is Exactly Like Below,

```
Expanded(child:     
ListView(children:tWidgets),),]);
```

My Code works fine without ListView like this

```
return Column(children: tWidgets,);
```

Comment: Try returning only Listview instead of wrapping with column & Expanded.

Comment: what is tWidgets ?

Answer (score 0):

`Expanded` Widgets only work inside Row and Column widgets, they cannot be used outside of these two widgets, so your solution will be like this

```dart
return Column(children: [
       Expanded( child: ListView(children: tWidgets,),)
  ],
);
```

Comment: Hello Thank You For your help i still get same error after i wrap it with column widget.          
 Is there anything in your mind that can help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Comment: It gives same error after adding shrinkWrap: true, to listview

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by fixing the order of my interface.
ListView was inside a Column and that column was also inside another column. I simply deleted a column.
if you are facing with this problem check the hierarchy of your interface.